# Ruby: Catching All Methods Sent to an Object

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm making a weird class where I want to catch every method sent to an object of the class. I can achieve most of what I want with method_missing e.g.

```
class MyClass
    def method_missing m, *args
        # do stuff
    end
end
```

The problem then is all of the instance methods that MyClass inherits from Object. I could go through each method one-by-one and redefine them, but I was hoping for a more flexible approach. All of the metaprogramming methods I've tried have complained with a NameError when I try to touch those instance methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As noted in the comments and the answer from @DanCheail, if you're using ruby 1.9+ you should use a `BasicObject` rather than undefining methods of `Object`.  At the time of this posting usage of 1.8.x was still quite prevalent, even though 1.9 had been released for some time.

---

Rather than attempting to "redefine" anything, you could wrap your object in a blanked (for the most part) proxy object, something like:

```
class MyProxy
  instance_methods.each do |meth|
    # skipping undef of methods that "may cause serious problems"
    undef_method(meth) if meth !~ /^(__|object_id)/
  end

  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
  end     

  def method_missing(*args)
    # do stuff
    p args
    # ...
    @object.send(*args)
  end
end

MyProxy.new(MyClass.new).whatever
```

Comment: It is much better to use a BasicObject, since it accomplishes the same thing and is much safer.

Comment: Noted.  When this answer was posted 1.8 was still pretty common in production scenarios, and as such `BasicObject` did not yet exist.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Ruby 1.9, you can have your class inherit from `BasicObject` to get a clean slate to work from:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/BasicObject.html

Comment: That's the sort of thing I'm looking for, but a trivial attempt gives me a `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` when defining `method_missing`. Hm...

Comment: What are you doing inside `method_missing`?  If you did something like `puts *args` you're going to get an infinite `method_missing` loop.  If you need a `Kernel` method you'd have to call `::Kernel.puts`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ruby 1.8 you can consider using the blankslate gem.